# Univariate Spline Interpolation is all NaNs but no signs of malformed arguments

Tags: python, ipython, interpolation, spline

I have created a function to created a spline interpolation function that does error checking on the input data and if it passes creates a spline with an amount of points which is a multiple times the original amount. But it seems to not be working even though  none of my error checking is raising a flag.

I error check for the following things:

- x and y data same size
- multiple (the factor of points to create) must be greater than zero, <1 is less points in spline, >1 is more points in spline, 1 is same amount of points
- the order of the spline must be between 1 and 5 (inclusive)
- the x data must be strictly monotonically increasing
- either the x or y data has at least one NaN in it

I feel as though this is a thorough list that would cause the spline to create a spline of all NaNs, but none of these errors are being raised when i feed it the data.

Here is the code

```
##
# Univariate Spline Interpolation
##

## This function interpolates the data by creating multiple times the amount of points in the data set and fitting a spline to it
## Input:
# dataX - X axis that you corresponds to dataset
# dataY - Y axis of data to fit spline on (must be same size as dataX)
# multiple - the multiplication factor, default is 2 ( <1 - Less points, 1 - same amount of points, >1 - more points)
# order - order of spline, default is 4 (3 - Cubic, 4 - Quartic)
## Output
# spline - interpolation spline object to be used for peak detection
# splinedDataX - splined X Axis
# splinedDataY - splined Y Axis

#import scipy modules for spling creation and class methods
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, LSQUnivariateSpline

#import numpy module for linear spacing creation
from numpy import linspace, NaN

def univariate_spline_interpolation(dataX, dataY, multiple=2, order=4):

    #Libraries
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, LSQUnivariateSpline
    from myUnivariateSpline import MyUnivariateSpline

    #Find sizes of x and y axis for comparison and multiple
    sizeX = len(dataX)
    sizeY = len(dataY)

    #Error catching
    if(sizeX != sizeY):
        print "Data X axis and Y axis must have same size"
        return

    if(multiple <= 0):
        print "Multiple must be greater than 0"
        return

    if(order < 1 or order >5):
        print "Order must be 1 <= order <= 5"
        return

    #check for monotonic increasting function
    for indx, val in enumerate(dataX): #set first value as largest value, need to have all following increase
        if indx == 0:
            high = val
            highIndx = indx
            continue
        #if the curent value is lower than 
        if val <= high:
            print "timestamp out of order"
            print "value at ", highIndx, "is ", high
            print "value at ", indx, "is ", val
            break

    #check for NaN in x and y
    for indx, val in enumerate(dataY):
        if(val == NaN):
            print "Value in Data Y at indx", indx, "is NaN"
            return

    for indx, val in enumerate(dataX):
        if(val == NaN):
            print "Value in Data X at indx", indx, "is NaN"
            return

    #Create Spline
    spline = UnivariateSpline(dataX, dataY, k=order, s=0)   

    #Create new axis based on numPoints
    numPoints = sizeX * multiple   #Find number of points for spline
    startPt = dataX[0]   #find value of first point on x axis
    endPt = dataX[-1]   #find value of last point on x axis
    splinedDataX = linspace(startPt, endPt, numPoints)   #create evenly spaced points on axis based on start, end, and number of desired data points

    #Create Y axis of splined Data
    splinedDataY = spline(splinedDataX)   #Create new Y axis with numPoints etnries of data splined to fit the original data

    return spline, splinedDataX, splinedDataY
```

And Here is one of the three data sets i am trying to feed it, but all of the three cause it to return NaNs in the splinedDataY field. The size of the interpDataY is the same as its corresponding interpDataX. I don't know what could be causing it to return only NaNs

[X Data](http://pastebin.com/9YC0icyX)
[Y Data](http://pastebin.com/EFvVxrMZ)

The both sets of data are pandas Series, but even casting them as lists doesn't resolve the issue

I dont know if this is revlevant but when i print the list it is a bunch of nan not NaN

Answer (score 0):

The X data on row 152 and 153 are identical: 5.86868286133. This is probably the cause. I do not know why your checking codes did not catch this as I am not familar with Python. But I supposed you should be able to figure it out.